# why this issue happens in my python code in second list comprehension but not in first one?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Please clarify why im getting below error while executing second list comprehension while first in not throwing any error?

```
k = range(1,20)
n=[KMeans(n_clusters=i) for i in k]
pred = [n[i].fit(df_s).inertia_ for i in k]
plt.plot(pred)
```

> 2 n=[KMeans(n_clusters=i) for i in k]
>
> ----> 3 pred = [n[i].fit(df_s).inertia_ for i in k]
>
> 4 plt.plot(pred)
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because your range value starts from 1 which is correct parameter for n_cluster in kmeans (which cannot be zero) but while fitting the model with different n values you are using list index which starts from zero as default and ranges to 18 in your case but your code while reaches ends it searches for 19th index(since it started from 1 in k) which is not there in list. Please try this code

```
k = range(1,20)
n=[KMeans(n_clusters=i) for i in k]
pred = [n[i-1].fit(df_s).inertia_ for i in k]
plt.plot(pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

The indices of the items in `n` will be 0 to 18, while your range goes from 1 to 19, so you'll get an error when trying to access `n[19]`.

You should do:

```
pred = [kmean.fit(df_s).inertia_ for kmean in n]
```

thus avoiding the use of indices.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) it also worked :)

Comment: More generally, you should really avoid using indices when iterating on lists, this can lead to all sorts of problems, complicates the code and makes it both less efficient and less readable.

Comment: Agreed your point.Thanks :)